# curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to start for PHP upgrade to 8.2.x in WordPress application

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, docker, networking

I am running a WordPress application on a CentOS Linux on-prem server using Docker. I recently upgraded the PHP image from 8.1.19 to 8.2.7. I am able to make it run in a lower environment server and in my local, but when I try to run it on a different server. I am not able to update the plugins, when I checked by going into the container and tried `curl -I google.com`, it throws the following error

```
root@sample-app-qa:/var/www/html# curl -I google.com
curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to star
```

When I checked the listening ports in the server

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      43087/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      43073/docker-proxy
```

It shows that its using IPv6 for ports 80 and 443 for `docker-proxy`. Is this whats the causing the issue? Coz when I check on other servers and in my local its using IPv4

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      121790/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      121775/docker-proxy
```

If this is the issue how can I force docker to use IPv4 for ports 80 and 443? Also, the issue was not there until PHP 8.1.19 and lower, the issue started occurring only for 8.2.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using an older version of Docker on the server `Docker version 18.09.7` . I was able to update the Docker to a more latest version `Docker version 24.0.4` and that solved the issue.

Comment: If isn't possible to upgrade docker right now, test downgrading the base image, in my case from bookworm to bullseye.